# Error in mysql #1241 — The operand must contain 1 columns. How do I make an alternative working request?

Tags: mysql

I understand that in the IN operator, and more precisely in SELECT, it is impossible to select two columns. Could you write an alternative of the same query or fix this one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `board` 
WHERE moder=0 AND activ=0 AND id_akk IN (SELECT user_id_to, user_id_from                                         
                                         FROM `podpiski` 
                                         WHERE user_id_from='38')
```

Comment: You are selecting 2 columns inside the IN, you can only select one

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should combine the two ids

```
SELECT * 
FROM `board` 
WHERE moder=0 AND activ=0 AND id_akk IN (SELECT user_id_to
                                         FROM `podpiski` 
                                         WHERE user_id_from='38'
                                         union
                                         SELECT user_id_from
                                         FROM `podpiski` 
                                         WHERE user_id_from='38')
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to match id_akk to either user_id_to or user_id_from.

But when you use the form you showed, using `IN()` with a subquery, SQL doesn't know how to compare one operand to multiple operands per row of the subquery. It's like trying to compare

```
WHERE mycolumn = (123, 456)
```

That doesn't make any sense. How can one value be equal to a pair of values?

So when comparing one value to a subquery using `IN()`, the subquery must return just one column.

Here's a workaround for your case:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM `board` AS b 
JOIN (SELECT user_id_to, user_id_from 
      FROM `podpiski` 
      WHERE user_id_from='38') AS p
  ON b.id_akk IN (p.user_id_to, p.user_id_from)
WHERE moder=0 AND activ=0
```

Or alternatively, do it simply with JOIN without a subquery:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM `board` AS b 
JOIN `podpiski` AS p 
  ON b.id_akk IN (p.user_id_to, p.user_id_from)
WHERE moder=0 AND activ=0
  AND p.user_id_from='38'
```

This way the `IN()` predicate is not using a subquery, it's using a list of scalar values. Then the comparison works, because this usage of `IN()` will just compare id_akk to each value in the list.

However, this has a problem. The JOIN can't use an index, so this will force a table-scan on the board table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to remove the `user_id_from` in the inner query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `board` 
WHERE moder=0 AND activ=0 AND id_akk IN (SELECT user_id_to                                         
                                         FROM `podpiski` 
                                         WHERE user_id_from='38')
```